# How to change the application to open pdf file in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, evince, adobe-reader

In Firefox, when I clicked a pdf file in website, I would be asked to download the pdf file or open the pdf file in  evince running outside Firefox.

Since I install Adobe Reader, whenever I clicked a pdf link, the pdf will be opened in it running inside Firefox.

I feel it is now running more slowly than before. Is it possible to change which application to open pdf from within Firefox?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > Applications

Answer (score 0):

You can't "install Adobe in wine" Adobe is a company, not a software. Adobe make a LOT of different softwares.

Do you stil have evince installed? If not then you can run:

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/acroread /usr/bin/evince

and it should fly, If you have evince installed too then this won't work so well. You may find firefox honours the default apps set for files so you may need to right click a PDF to set acroread as the default app to open PDfs with and it should make the browser behave appropriately.

Comment: -1, it's a bad idea to symlink `acroread` to `evince`. The two are not compatible. While it may work in some cases, it may also break terribly in other cases.

Answer (score -3):

I personally don't use firefox, I use chrome, but if you wan't to change something poke around in preferences for both firefox and for adobe and see if you can find anything.  Also you might consider closing firefox after downloading the file and just viewing it in adobe reader outside of firefox.  If you can't stand doing that you might be able to install adobe in WINE and then it won't interfere with firefox.